# Using two different version of OpenCV in one CMake project

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

My project is based on CMake and uses OpenCV 3.1 and its contrib package. However, I also want to include a library (also a CMake project, I have access to the source and can build it on my own) which relies on OpenCV 2.x.x (because of [this](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/issues/4819) "bug" it's not compatible to OpenCV 3).

Is there any chance that I can use this library by linking OpenCV 2.x.x into it and link all together to my executable or similar?

Currently I have built OpenCV 3.1 and OpenCV 2.4.13 on my system and I am able to use them separately (in my project respectively in an example program using the library).

Comment: From what I can tell based on a [quick look at the library](https://github.com/wg-perception/PartsBasedDetector/blob/master/include/PartsBasedDetector.hpp), it uses OpenCV in the interface, so I'd vouch for a definite no. Unless you can fix the problem with the library itself, I'd suggest just using version 2.4.13 in your code as well. If you need 3.x specifically, then perhaps 2 programs and some IPC?

Comment: I think the shortest way is to patch your other library and adapt it to work with the OpenCV 3 interface. Indeed, having OpenCV in the interface you cannot have multiple incompatible versions at the same time.

Comment: I have feared that, nevertheless thank you for your help. I will try to upgrade the library (once more:).

Answer (score 0):

You have to do something like [this](http://answers.opencv.org/question/89142/baserowfilter-and-basecolumnfilter-in-opencv-3x/) or  [this](http://answers.opencv.org/question/66169/how-can-i-use-lmsolver-to-solve-a-non-linear-system/) :
copy opencv sourcefile in your sourcefile and it works...